# Stop a block copying a variable

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to pass a delegate through a method to another object. It works briefly, but then becomes null. I think I've figured out what's causing it but not how to solve it.

So Blocks in iOS automatically copy any variables that are referenced. I have a method where the user passes in a delegate object. A block is executed for a managed object context, which in turn makes a web request where the delegate is passed. What I think is happening, is this block is making a copy of the delegate object, and the passing it on to the request, but then the block finishes execution and the delegate is released.

Is there a way I can simply pass the original delegate object through rather than the block making a copy of it?

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[MPCoreDataManager sharedInstance] managedObjectContext];
[context performBlock:^{
    __block NSError *error;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([self class])];
    [request setSortDescriptors:@[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:key ascending:asc selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]]];

    NSFetchedResultsController *controller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                                 managedObjectContext:context
                                                                                   sectionNameKeyPath:keyPath
                                                                                            cacheName:nil];

    [controller performFetch:&error];

    if (!controller.fetchedObjects || controller.fetchedObjects.count == 0) {
        // Nothing found or an error, query the server instead
                NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", kMP_BASE_API_URL, [self baseURL]];
        MPRequest *objRequest = [MPRequest requestWithURL:url];
          objRequest.delegate = delegate;

        [objRequest setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
        [MPUser signRequest:objRequest];

        [objRequest submit:^(MPResponse *resp, NSError *err) {
            if (err) {
                block(nil, err);
            } else {
                NSArray *objects = [self createListWithResponse:resp];
                         objects = [MPModel saveAllLocally:objects forEntityName:NSStringFromClass([self class])];
                [controller performFetch:&error];
                block(controller, nil);
            }

        }];

    } else {
        // Great, we found something :)
        block (controller, nil);
    }
}];
```

This is the code I'm using. As you can see, the delegate is used here `objRequest.delegate = delegate;` but is being released by ARC as it is a copy and not the original.

How can I get around this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it sorted. Was a mixture of me being an idiot and not realising that the output from my NSLog saying the delegate was null was infact a different request entirely, and the memory management of blocks.

Comment: maybe you could accept this answer, delete the question or provide another explaining answer :)

Comment: ahh sorry! I was meant to accept the answer but it wouldn't let me initially as the question was too new. Done now :)

Answer (score -1):

The block does not copy the objects inside it, it just captures them (increases ARC retain count).

I suppose that your delegate is a weak reference, it doesn't get captured by the block for this reason. You could solve this problem by passing to the block a strong reference to the delegate.

Comment: I don't need the delegate to be retained though. The delegate in this case is a view controller so it's not being released, and my delegate for the request is defined as `@property (nonatomic, weak)`. Surely if I passed the delegate as strong, it would retain it again?

Comment: Well you said that the delegate if release. If that's the case you need to retain it. If you pass it as strong yes, it will increase it's ARC retain count.

Comment: The block copies the values of all the variables it captures at the time the block is created, unless the variable is declared `__block`, in which case it holds a reference to the variable. For captured variables that are pointer to objects, it also retains them when the block is copied.

Comment: @newacct I have said that "The block does not copy the objects inside it", not that it doesn't copy the variables inside it. This in reply to the OP saying this: "What I think is happening, is this block is making a copy of the delegate object [...]".